# Azure Python SDK for Blobs - ImportError: cannot import name 'BlobClient' (python 3.8.7)

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

With Python 3.8.7 I have a problem importing Python Azure SDK for Blobs !

```
cannot import name 'BlobClient' from 'azure.storage.blob
```

I used this :

```
pip install azure-storage-blob
```

I checked the connection string value and still have the problem.

I am running it in a python 3.8.7 venv.
I have just tested it locally  without the venv, I can import and it works.

Is there any specificity while using a venv ?

I have just test it with the python 3.8.7 version and I got always the some problem even after doing the upgrade

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you have written.

Comment: "I have just tested it locally without the venv, I can import and it works. Is there any specificity while using a venv ?"—well, yes, you need to install it _in the virtual environment_. Make sure you have the correct environment activated when you run your `pip install`.